# Notepad++ - Find first instance of "," in one line with "find and replace" function

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

I want to find the first instance of "," in a line Notepad++. I feel this might be an easy answer, but I have tried to find an solution for quite some time now.

I have the following example data that I want to replace:

```
K8.transform.position = new Vector3 (-1249.966,-0.055,1250.139)*ObjectScale ; K1.transform.Rotate(0.000000,0.000000,0.000000) ;
```

with this:

```
K8.transform.position = new Vector3 (-1249.966f,-0.055f,1250.139f)*ObjectScale ; K1.transform.Rotate(0.000000f,0.000000f,0.000000f) ;
```

The only difference is that all values have an additional "f" in the end. I have tried code similar to

```
Vector3 \(.*,
```

to start to find the first value. But it does not find the first "," but the last one in each row,
[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvXmJ.png).

As I said, I feel this might be an easy answer, but I can't find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you search for a dot followed by one or more digits:

```
\.(\d+)
```

and then replace this with the found text and append the `f`:

```
\.\1f
```

Here is a detailed link how to use [Notepad++ Regex](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\d)(?=[,)])`
- Replace with: `f`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\d)  : lookbehind, make sure we have a digit before current position
(?=[,)]) : lookahead, make sure we have a comma or a close parenthesis after current position
```

**Result for given example:**

```
K8.transform.position = new Vector3 (-1249.966f,-0.055f,1250.139f)*ObjectScale ; K1.transform.Rotate(0.000000f,0.000000f,0.000000f) ;
```

Comment: I tested this, but it didn't work. I get an "^ zero length match" response, and it doesn't make any changes in the text. But TmTron's suggestion worked, thanks anyway!

Comment: @StrawCap: Strange, what version are you using? Here it is `7.5.1`

Comment: I also use 7.5.1, strange.